# C malloc to pointer to NULL not working

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am writing a function that inserts a new node in a binary search tree. In order to avoid having too many if-else's, I am using a pointer called `nodeSide` that points to either node's left or right, as follows:

```
void insertHelper(Node *node, int val) {

  Node *nodeSide;
  if (val < node->val) {
    nodeSide = node->left;
  } else {
    nodeSide = node->right;
  }

  if (nodeSide == NULL) {
    nodeSide = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nodeSide->val = val;
    nodeSide->left = NULL;
    nodeSide->right = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else {
    insertHelper(nodeSide, val);
  }
}
```

The node however, isn't actually being added. It seems like doing this:

```
Node *node =  malloc(...);
node->left = NULL;
Node *anotherNode = nodeLeft;
anotherNode = malloc(...);
```

doesn't in fact add a new node to tree. Any ideas why? The pointer should be pointing to the right place, regardless whether it is null or not. Or am I wrong here?

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _node {
  int val;
  struct _node * left;
  struct _node * right;
  int ht;
} Node;


void insertHelper(Node *node, int val) {

  Node *nodeSide;
  if (val < node->val) {
    nodeSide = node->left;
  } else {
    nodeSide = node->right;
  }

  if (nodeSide == NULL) {
    nodeSide = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nodeSide->val = val;
    nodeSide->left = NULL;
    nodeSide->right = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else {
    insertHelper(nodeSide, val);
  }
}

Node * getNode(int value) {
  Node * node = (Node * )malloc(sizeof(Node));
  node->val = value;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  node->ht = 0;
  return node;
}

Node * getTree() {
  Node *root = getNode(3);
  Node *rootLeft = getNode(2);
  root->left = rootLeft;
  Node *rootRight = getNode(4);
  root->right = rootRight;
  Node *rootRightRight = getNode(5);
  rootRight->right = rootRightRight;
  return root;
}

int main() {

  Node * root = getTree();

  insertHelper(root, 6);

  // to verify:
  printf("%d", root->right->right->right->val);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. Describe what happens and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl I did explain saying that the new node doesn't get added at all. The tree remains in the original state. See `doesn't in fact add a new node to tree` and the code snippet before it.

Comment: You copy address by value and then replace it with new address, But because you copy it by value, it doesn't changes in first place. For example int i = 5, j = 6; i = j; i = 7. j == 6, not 7.

Comment: @darksky :  This is the kind of problem best investigated using a debugger.  SO is not a debugger.  Step through the code, observe the variables, fix the problem.

Comment: @user1516873 where am I copying by value?

Comment: here: nodeSide = node->right;

Comment: @Clifford I did. I'm not sure if you read the entire post carefully but as I said, the malloced node isn't being added to the correct `nodeSide` such that on return, `node->right` or (`nodeSide`) doesn't contain the malloced object anymore.

Comment: @user1516873 but isn't that just assigning one pointer to another? Which isn't by value?

Comment: beside the problem you have stumbled upon: there's really no need for `insertHelper()` to be recursive and could even end in an endless recursion (imagine you have nodes with val 1 and 2 and try to add another val 1)

Comment: nos's answer is perfect, check his example and find a difference with your code.

Comment: looking at your comments to the answers you seem to forget that in your code `node->left` (or right) and `nodeSide` are *two different* variables that may contain a noed's address. So if you assign a value to one of them the other is not affected and the address is forgotten when `insertHelper()` terminates

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yup you're right. That's the answer I'm looking for. That's why double pointers resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not store the new node that you create anywhere in your tree.

Perhaps you could do e.g.

```
if (nodeSide == NULL) {
    nodeSide = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nodeSide->val = val;
    nodeSide->left = NULL;
    nodeSide->right = NULL;
    if (val < node->val)
       node->left = nodeSide;
    } else {
       node->right = nodeSide;
    }
    return;
  }
```

But you could use a double pointer, to avoid the extra if/else there:

```
  Node **nodeSide;
  if (val < node->val) {
    nodeSide = &node->left;
  } else {
    nodeSide = &node->right;
  }

  if (*nodeSide == NULL) {
    *nodeSide = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*nodeSide)->val = val;
    (*nodeSide)->left = NULL;
    (*nodeSide)->right = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else {
    insertHelper(*nodeSide, val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really because nodeSide at the beginning of the insert function points to either `node->right` or `node->left`. So I just malloced the new node to it.

Comment: @nos @IngoLeonhardt I see why you're using a double pointer but why doesn't my code work though? `nodeSide` will point to `node->right` or `node->left` which is NULL, and then the malloced object gets assigned to that pointer. So accessing `node->left/right` should work. Why do I need to use double pointers?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Nvm, answered my question above.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt No, with a double pointer, *nodeside is  either the original node->left or node->right, and that's where the new malloc'ed node gets stored.  (*nodeSide)->left would be within the newly created node, which should set to NULL.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Then you're creating a cyclic loop in your tree, and your binary search tree is most certainly not going to work like you intended it to. The binary tree in question here also does not have a link from a node back to a parent node (which is fine for the intended usage)

Answer (score -1):

Youre `insertHelper` seems to lack one relevant line of code just before the `return`:

```
node->left = nodeSide;
```

But keep in mind which side to add the value. Maybe you should track the relevant side as variable inside the function.

Comment: Nope because nodeSide is `node->left` or `node->right`.

Comment: @darksky Yes, it was an example. That's why I wrote 'But keep in mind which side to add the value.'... thanks for reading and the vote, dude.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense what you're saying. Assigning node->left to its pointer doesn't make sense. Sorry.

Comment: At the moment of the assignment `node->left` is a pointer to `NULL` which differs strongly from the value of `nodeSide` which is in fact what you want, a valid and allocated `Node` which was created just before. Simply look at the accepted answer and what this guy is doing... pretty the same but he made up the rest which saves you from thinking... keep it going.